# Rename filename using another files name from the same folder

Tags: batch-file, filenames, rename, copy-paste

I currently have a windows folder with only two files in it:
vacation.jpg
and 
summer.avi

What I want to to is rename summer.avi in vacation.avi by using the text that is before the .jpg extension.

So for example if I have another folder with christmas.jpg and summer.avi the .avi file would be renamed into christmas.avi.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `~n` parameter extension to grab just the filename without the extension. The script needs to be in the same directory as the jpg and avi, but if you want to run it on multiple directories, you can wrap the whole thing in a second `for` loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: This assumes there is only one avi file in the folder
for /F %%A in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
    set basename=%%~nA
    ren *.avi !basename!.avi
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Your code does something but not completely what it should do. It changes the file to ".avi" so it doesn't show anything before the extension.

Comment: @Azaemol - I made a rookie mistake and forgot to enable delayed expansion to access a variable I set inside of a code block. I've edited my code; try it now.

Answer (score -1):

This should worlk, though I haven't tested it:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.jpg) do set src=%%i
ren *.avi %src%
```

Comment: This is going to rename the avi file to the same filename as the jpg, _including_ the extension. Fortunately, batch won't allow this to happen since a file with that name already exists, so this won't do anything at all.