# Rename filename using another files name from the same folder with FOR loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

If found a very helpful batch script at [Rename filename using another files name from the same folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943950/rename-filename-using-another-files-name-from-the-same-folder)

It works:

```
    @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: This assumes there is only one avi file in the folder
for /F %%A in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
    set basename=%%~nA
    ren *.avi !basename!.avi
)
```

But how I can add a additional FOR loop that will do it for every subfolder. I have many subfolders that require renaming. Another problem is, that after the renaming only the first name of the filename is taken. After the space in the file name the script cuts the file name.

The structure is as follows:

Folder
------------subfolder
---------------------file.jpg
---------------------notagoodfilename.avi

after good Batchscript:

Folder
------------subfolder
---------------------file.jpg
---------------------file.avi

This script should work for every subfolder. Folder --> subfolder, subfolder1 ...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your script doesn't make much sense, please try to fully explain your intended task. This appears to rename any `.avi` in the current directory to the name of the last matched `.jpg` in that directory. The only way it would work properly would be if there was control over directories with only one copy of a `.jpg` and only one copy of an `.avi`

Comment: Ok, I have folders with subfolders and in the subfolders there are filenames that does not fit to me. So .avi filenames should be renamed after the correct .jpg filenames in every subdirectory, that is my intention.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're going to have to provide a considerably better explanation of your directory and file structure with examples before and after the renaming. To do that you need to use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45755524/edit) facility, to update the question instead of posting updates in the comment area.

Comment: Ok I hope now with this explanation it will make more sense.

Comment: So each subfolder contains exactly two files: one is .jpg and the other is a .avi. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you telling us that all directories will always contain both of those file types only once?

Comment: no there are some other files too, for example one .log file but this file should not be touched. Only .jpg .avi should be involved in the script and only .avi files should be renamed. And yes all subfolders contains these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your previous script could be simplified to the following one-liner:

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do ren *.avi %%~na.*
```

To do this in all subfolders of the current folder:

```
for /r %%a in (*.jpg) do ren %%~dpa*.avi %%~na.*
```

UPDATE:
Following the comments to this answer, here's a better version:

```
for /r "C:\Path\To\Top\Folder" %%a in (*.jpg) do ren "%%~dpa*.avi" "%%~na.*"
```

Comment: just make sure that either the current directory is a parent of your target subdirectories or that you insert "C:\PathToParent" after **`/r `**.

Comment: for /r "C:\PathToParent" %%a in (*.jpg) do ren %%~dpa*.avi %%~na.* then in got a syntax error :-(

"in" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.

Comment: @noobcoder you've missed out a `*` from your command line. It should be `for /r "C:\PathToParent" %%a in (*.jpg) do ren %%~dpa*.avi %%~na.*` Note the `*` between `%%~dpa` and `.avi`.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to put the file names in quotes just in case they contain spaces: `for /r "C:\PathToParent" %%a in (*.jpg) do ren "%%~dpa*.avi" "%%~na.*"`

Comment: I just noticed that StackOverflow sometimes removes some asterisks from comments. So I'm not sure if you left out an asterisk or SO removed it. Anyway, please try my updated answer (with the filenames in quotes) and let me know if it works.

Comment: Hmm thank you I tried it but with the same result:

"in" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.

I used the quotes

Comment: my failure now it works, I started the wrong scriptfile.